# How to integrate icons within my code from weatherapi.com

Tags: api, weather-api

Earlier I was using OpenWeatherAPI and for my icon code it would look something like:

```
const { icon, description } = data.weather[0];
&
document.querySelector(".icon").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
```

now I am trying to do the same for weatherapi.com, my code looks like this:

```
const { icon } = data.current.condition.icon;
&
document.querySelector(".icon").src = "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/" + icon + "/113.png"
```

but this doesn;t work. I believe I am accessing the data correctly from the source, see http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=c014ca23bca74b9f82f130128222406&q=seattle&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no for an example json file
but maybe the queryselector line is wrong. Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not correct for getting the image. Firstly, I've found that you need to add `https:` before the `//` at the start of the string to define a protocol.
Secondly, between `/64x64/` and `/113.png`, should come either `day` or `night`, not the number of your image. The fixed string would look like this:

```
"https://cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/" + icon + ".png"
```

If this still doesn't work, I would recommend downloading the zip of the icons to your local machine and accessing them from there. The link to the zip can be found on the bottom of https://www.weatherapi.com/docs/ and is https://cdn.weatherapi.com/weather.zip